# Viscous Burgers' equation with a coefficient to the nonlinear term

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics

I am considering the following PDE
\begin{equation}
u_t
+
\alpha
\,
u
u_x
-
\beta
\,
u_{xx}
=
0
\end{equation}
with $\alpha, \beta > 0$.
When $\alpha = 1$, this is the viscous Burgers' equation. Given a solution for a case with $\alpha = 1$, I would like to know how this is changed by assuming $\alpha \neq 1$.

I will certainly benefit from the writing of the new solution but also from the explanation of the methodology to obtain that. So in the future I can adapt the reasoning to new initial and boundary conditions.

---

The domain is $x \in [-\infty,\infty]$ and $t \in [0,\infty[$.

At the boundary:
$$
u(-\infty,t) = 1 \\
u(\infty,t) = 0
$$
The initial conditions describe a step change at the origin:
$$
u(x,0) = 1
\textrm{ for }
x \leq 0
\\
u(x,0) = 0
\textrm{ for }
x \geq 0
$$

---

The solution for the viscous Burgers equation is
$$
u(x,t) =
\frac
{ % numerator
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
\frac
{x - \xi}
{t}
e^{-G}
\,
d\xi
}{ % denominator
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{-G}
\,
d\xi
} % end fraction
$$
with
$$
G(\xi; x,t) =
\frac{1}{2\beta}
\left(
\int_0^\xi
u(\xi',0)
\,
d\xi'
+
\frac
{(x-\xi)^2}
{2t}
\right)
$$

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can transform the equation to the case where both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are unity by rescaling the time and position coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Approach $1$:

Let $\begin{cases}x_1=x\\t_1=\alpha t\end{cases}$ ,

Then $u_x=u_{x_1}(x_1)_x+u_{t_1}(t_1)_x=u_{x_1}$

$u_{xx}=(u_{x_1})_{x_1}(x_1)_x+(u_{x_1})_{t_1}(t_1)_x=u_{x_1x_1}$

$u_t=u_{x_1}(x_1)_t+u_{t_1}(t_1)_t=\alpha u_{t_1}$

$\therefore\alpha u_{t_1}+\alpha uu_{x_1}-\beta u_{x_1x_1}=0$

$u_{t_1}+uu_{x_1}-\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha}u_{x_1x_1}=0$

Which converts to the viscous Burgers' equation.

Approach $2$:

Let $\begin{cases}x_2=\dfrac{x}{\alpha}\\t_2=t\end{cases}$ ,

Then $u_x=u_{x_2}(x_2)_x+u_{t_2}(t_2)_x=\dfrac{u_{x_2}}{\alpha}$

$u_{xx}=(u_{x_2})_{x_2}(x_2)_x+(u_{x_2})_{t_2}(t_2)_x=\dfrac{u_{x_2x_2}}{\alpha^2}$

$u_t=u_{x_2}(x_2)_t+u_{t_2}(t_2)_t=u_{t_2}$

$\therefore u_{t_2}+uu_{x_2}-\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha^2}u_{x_2x_2}=0$

Which converts to the viscous Burgers' equation.

Comment: Thx. For a complete answer, would you mind to re-write the solution for the problem given? So I (anyone) can check out my (his/her) understanding against your suggestion. Then, it is intriguing, but a bit disconcerting for the novice, that the second derivative can have either $\beta/\alpha$ or $\beta/\alpha^2$ as coefficient --- are perhaps the variables subscripts of the second approach 2's instead of 1's?